# Difficulty writing tests, getting wrong responses?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-testing, django-tests

My problem: I'm writing tests and I'm getting 302 responses instead of 200. I figure this is kind of expected because when a user isn't logged in and isn't assigned to the group Employee_Management, they will always be redirected.

So I'm trying to create a user and add it to the group, but I have no idea how to check if the user is actually logged in, or if it is part of the group. I get no errors from the setUp, but the test still fails and gives me a 302. So my guess is I've messed up my setUp. Ideas?

view:

```
@method_decorator(group_required('Employee_Management'), name='dispatch')
class ListActiveView(TemplateView):

def get(self, request):
    users = User.objects.all().exclude(is_superuser=True)
    return render(request, 'user/list_active.html', {
        'users': users,
    })
```

urls:

```
app_name = 'user'
urlpatterns = [path('list_active/', ListActiveView.as_view(), name='list_active')]
```

test:

```
class TestListActive(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create(username='testuser', password='testuserpass')
        emp_man = Group.objects.create(name='Employee_Management')
        user.groups.add(emp_man)
        c = Client()
        c.login(username='testuser', password='testuserpass')

    def test_list_active_url(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('user:list_active'))
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you use two `Client` instances.

The first one (`c`) is the one you create in `setUp`, which your user is logged to but that is never used again.

The other one is the `TestCase` instance's client (`self.client`) which you use in `test_list_active_url` and which your user is not logged in to.

To fix that, always use the `TestCase` instance's client:

```
class TestListActive(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create(username='testuser', password='testuserpass')
        emp_man = Group.objects.create(name='Employee_Management')
        user.groups.add(emp_man)
        self.client.login(username='testuser', password='testuserpass')

    def test_list_active_url(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('user:list_active'))
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: This doesn't change my results though. I still get a 302 response, while I should be getting a 200. Is there a way that my test can show which user is logged in and what group it belongs to?

Comment: You can try `django.contrib.auth.get_user(self.client)`

Comment: Feel like I'm in way over my head, changed the username to a non existing name, test doesn't seem to care and pass it anyway. What's the point of creating a test user if the test ignores it. Can't see the logged in user, can't see it's group.

Comment: I used to check the result of the login to ensure that succeed `self.assertTrue(self.client.login(username='testuser', password='testuserpass'))`. Also you can check at which url you are redirected